# Is there a simple way to copy my current buffer into a new buffer?

Tags: indirect-buffers

Say I'm editing a file `~/mydirectory/foo.txt`.

I'd like to be able to issue a command `M-x switch-to-bar-file` that copies current contents of  `~/mydirectory/foo.txt` to a file `~/mydirectory/foo-bar.txt` and drops me into a new buffer where I can edit `~/mydirectory/foo-bar.txt`.

When I'm done editing `~/mydirectory/foo-bar.txt`, I'd like to issue a command `M-x unswitch-from-bar-file` which copies the current contents of `~/mydirectory/foo-bar.txt` back over to `~/mydirectory/foo.txt` and drops me back into the buffer where I can edit `~/mydirectory/foo.txt`.

It seems that there may be a way to do this with [indirect buffers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html), but I can't quite figure out how to solve my problem.

Is this sort of thing possible?

I can post an example if that would help.

Comment: `write-file` (`C-x C-w`) doesn't meet your needs? I'm not sure what you're getting at here. This workflow seems very strange.

Comment: Maybe I didn't do a great job explaining. I'm trying to keep track of two versions of a latex document (one "quiz" and one "quiz-solutions").

Comment: Not to be snide, but the usual way one goes about that is to write the quiz, then fill in the solutions...

Comment: The reason I left out the context is because I wasn't interested in commentary on my workflow. I think for now your `write-file` recommendation will do.

Comment: Sounds like a job for org-mode. You can choose to export your solution or not. So you only need single file instead of switching and tracking between files

Comment: Note that indirect buffers are buffers which have literally the same content as the buffer they were created from -- if you edit the text in one of those buffers, you are editing it in all of the buffers. As far as I can tell, this isn't what you want, so you probably want to remove the `indirect-buffers` reference and tag.